# Write a spider in scrapy, but why 'yield item' not work in a nested for loop?

Tags: python, scrapy, yield

I have a spider writting in scrapy, but yiled item not executed in for loop, see code below.

```
def parse_paragraph(self, div_list, category_name, group_name):
    for div in div_list:
        duilian_text_list = div.xpath('./text()').extract()
        duilian_text_list = strip_list(duilian_text_list)
        if len(duilian_text_list) == 0:
            continue
        elif len(duilian_text_list) == 1:
            duilian_text = duilian_text_list[0]
            self.parse_duilian(duilian_text, category_name, group_name)
        elif len(duilian_text_list) == 2 and not is_single_line(duilian_text_list[0]):
            duilian_text = ''.join(duilian_text_list)
            self.parse_duilian(duilian_text, category_name, group_name)
        else:
            for duilian_text in duilian_text_list:
                duilian_item = DuilianItem()
                duilian_item['id'] = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-', '')
                duilian_item['category_id'] = getCategoryName(category_name)
                duilian_item['group_name'] = group_name
                duilian = parse_duilian(duilian_text)
                if duilian != '|':
                    duilian_item['name'] = duilian
                    duilian_item['desc'] = ''
                    duilian_item['author'] = ''
                    duilian_item['shuti'] = ''
                    duilian_item['word_count'] = len(duilian_item['name']) // 2
                    duilian_item['image_url'] = ''
                    print('-------I am here--------')
                    yield duilian_item
```

when i call this function, i got nothing in output window, it seems the line `yiled duilian_item` not work, and it even prevent other code to execute(the print line above it).

When i comment out the last line `yiled duilian_item`, everything works, and i got `-------I am here--------` in the output window, what's wrong here?

put it in a simple way, the following code print nothing, but if I comment out `yiled 1`, it print the list, so yield in python not work in a for loop?

```
def strange_yield():
    list = [1, 2, 3]
    for i in list:
        print(i)
        yield 1

strange_yield()
```

Comment: `parse_paragraph` is not the problem, it’s the function that calls it. Can you post it? Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Gallaecio you are right, post another thread here, waiting for your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776085/scrapy-custome-method-not-called

Comment: For someone who has the same problem, see [here] https://stackoverflow.com/a/58797244/1487475.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use yield in your python function, the function becomes a Generator Function. The correct way to deal with it following your `strange_yield` function is:

```
my_yield = strange_yield()
```

my_yield is now an instance of the Generator Function `strange_yield`. Generator Functions can be iterated over or can be pulled the next value by using the `next()` function:

```
print(next(my_yield))
```

or

```
for yield_value in my_yield:
  print(yield_value)
```

Comment: So, what can i do with my spider? in scrapy the last parse method need to yield an item, i am not just want to print it. sometimes I want to debug it, and the degugger cannot step into the code.