# Scrapy, custome method not called

Tags: python, scrapy

I met a problem when I parse a web page by scrapy, my custome method was not called by scrapy. the url is: http://www.duilian360.com/chunjie/117.html, and the code is:

```
import scrapy
from shufa.items import DuilianItem

class DuilianSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'duilian_spider'
    start_urls = [
        {"url": "http://www.duilian360.com/chunjie/117.html", "category_name": "春联", "group_name": "鼠年春联"},
    ]
    base_url = 'http://www.duilian360.com'

    def start_requests(self):
        for topic in self.start_urls:
            url = topic['url']
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url)

    def parse(self, response):
        div_list = response.xpath("//div[@class='contentF']/div[@class='content_l']/p")
        self.parse_paragraph(div_list)

    def parse_paragraph(self, div_list):
        for div in div_list:
            duilian_text_list = div.xpath('./text()').extract()
            for duilian_text in duilian_text_list:
                duilian_item = DuilianItem()
                duilian_item['category_id'] = 1
                duilian = duilian_text
                duilian_item['name'] = duilian
                duilian_item['desc'] = ''
                print('I reach here...')
                yield duilian_item
```

On above code, method `parse_paragraph` was not called, since the `print` clause has no output, I can't step into this method even when i set a breakpoint on the print line.

But if I move all code in method `parse_paragraph` into the calling method `parse_page` as below, then everything works well, why?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from shufa.items import DuilianItem

class DuilianSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'duilian_spider'
    start_urls = [
        {"url": "http://www.duilian360.com/chunjie/117.html", "category_name": "春联", "group_name": "鼠年春联"},
    ]
    base_url = 'http://www.duilian360.com'

    def start_requests(self):
        for topic in self.start_urls:
            url = topic['url']
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url)

    def parse(self, response):
        div_list = response.xpath("//div[@class='contentF']/div[@class='content_l']/p")
        for div in div_list:
            duilian_text_list = div.xpath('./text()').extract()
            for duilian_text in duilian_text_list:
                duilian_item = DuilianItem()
                duilian_item['category_id'] = 1
                duilian = duilian_text
                duilian_item['name'] = duilian
                duilian_item['desc'] = ''
                print('I reach here...')
                yield duilian_item

    # def parse_paragraph(self, div_list):
    #     for div in div_list:
    #         duilian_text_list = div.xpath('./text()').extract()
    #         for duilian_text in duilian_text_list:
    #             duilian_item = DuilianItem()
    #             duilian_item['category_id'] = 1
    #             duilian = duilian_text
    #             duilian_item['name'] = duilian
    #             duilian_item['desc'] = ''
    #             print('I reach here...')
    #             yield duilian_item
```

My code has lots of custome method, and I don't want the move all code in them to the calling method. this is not a good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use **yield from** instead direct calling `parse_paragraph` since that returns a **generator** rather than yielding items/requests from another parser.

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        div_list = response.xpath("//div[@class='contentF']/div[@class='content_l']/p")
        yield from self.parse_paragraph(div_list)
```

Comment: Brother, you saved me!

Comment: No problem at all =P